# Issues running Selenium with Chromedriver on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, raspberry-pi4

I wonder if anyone can help me with this error that I'm getting.

I want to use Selenium to monitor a web page on a (headless) Raspberry Pi 4 using Python. I have installed Selenium and installed the correct versions of Chromedriver that [needs to work with AMRHF](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/armhf/chromium-chromedriver) for Raspberry PIs;

Here are the versions of what i'm using:

```
chromium-browser:  Chromium 86.0.4240.197
chromedriver: 86.0.4240.197
python 3.7
selenium-3.141.0
```

Here is my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')

driver.get("https://www.google.com")

driver.close()
```

Here is the Traceback error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I've spent half a day on this trying different things and I'm lost.
Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, I'm running Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). I think I installed chromedriver using PIP. Do you think there is a problem with the chromedriver? maybe i shoudl reinstall?

Answer (score 6):

Install chromedriver using apt install:

```
sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver
```

If Chromium already installed check version, both Chromium and chromedriver should be same version.

Install Selenium using pip:

```
pip3 install selenium
```

Try to give permissions to already installed chromedriver:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver
```

Raspberry with Ubuntu 20.04 Server
[image]

Remove already installed Chromium [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084909/how-to-completely-remove-chromium-browser-from-ubuntu-18-04) and reinstall with chromedriver:

```
sudo apt purge --remove chromium-browser -y
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean -y
sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver
```

Comment: Thanks for this. When I tried to give permissions it said "operation not permitted". I then used "sudo chmod" and that worked fine.

I decided to run my script with "sudo python3 test.py" instead of the usual "python3 script.py" and I get; 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'`

Comment: First  install `sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver` chromedriver. Then install selenium: `pip3 install selenium`. That should work

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me @sers. When I ran them it simply said that they were both already installed. So unfortunately I get the same error at the moment that i was getting before.

`sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver
chromium-chromedriver is already the newest version (86.0.4240.197-rpt1).`
`pip3 install selenium
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from selenium) (1.24.1)`

Comment: I have Raspberry with Ubuntu 20.04 Server installed and there's no issue. Did you install Chrome separate? My version installed `sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver` is 87.0.4280.88. Installation of `chromium-chromedriver` installing Chromium also, no need to install it separately. Your issue is probably related to uncompatibility of driver and Chromium versions

Comment: Thanks for your help @sers but unfortunately that didnt work either. Were you running on ubuntu? As i'm on running on a Raspberry Pi - so maybe that's the difference?

Comment: Thank you @Sers